# cron job is not running on cpanel server

Tags: php, cpanel

I am trying to run following script in cron job section of cpanel but i am not getting any mail and my database is also not getting updated as script updates the database.

```
/usr/bin/php  /home/allsamac/public_html/getlinks/abc.php
php -q /public_html/getlinks/abc.php
```

Answer (score 0):

In crontab system :

```
1./usr/bin/php is php binary path (different in some systems ex: freebsd  /usr/local/bin/php, linux: /usr/bin/php)

2./home/username/public_html/cron/cron.php should be your php script path
3./dev/null should be cron output , ex: /home/username/stdoutx.txt
```

So you can monitor your cron by viewing cron output `/home/username/stdoutx.txt`

Comment: there is no such file named stdoutx.txt i tried everything what you said.

Comment: you have to use yr file`/home/username/abc.txt` i gave you an example

Comment: or `/home/username/abc.php`